# How to disabled number if the selected number is less than current time in the clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a solution actually I am using date field in appointment form but for "time field" I am using two dropdown as per the clients requirement "24hr clock", one dropdown is for  "Hours ex: 10,11,12,13..so on till 19," and another for "minutes : ex: 15,30,45,60". So beacuse of dropdown whenever user select the "date" and on that particular date he/she has to select time for booking appointment. Ex: Date "02/03/2018" and time is Hours: "10" and minutes: "30" but current time is hours: "11" and minutes:"30". But still its going to next page where it should say "the time has passed" I want to use this kind of feature. In think it is possible with javascript using " disabled attribute" so the number is greater than or less than functionality. Could anybody please help me with this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="select-container">
            <select class="form-control sel-event" id="hr" name="hours" required>
                <option value="">Choose Time/Hr</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="select-container">
            <select class="form-control sel-event" id="min" name="minutes" required>
                <option value="">Choose Time/Min</option>
                <option value="00">00 Min</option>
                <option value="15">15 Min</option>
                <option value="30">30 Min</option>
                <option value="45">45 Min</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

```
function myFunction() {

 var appointment_time =document.getElementById("hr").value

    var dt = new Date();
    var current_time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();

    //convert both time into timestamp
    var stt = new Date("Mar 02, 2018 " + appointment_time);
    stt = stt.getTime();

    var endt = new Date("Mar 02, 2018 " + current_time);
    endt = endt.getTime();

    //by this you can see time stamp value in console via firebug
    console.log("Time1: "+ stt + " Time2: " + endt);

    if(stt > endt) {
       alert('Submission time can not be less than of current time.');//to do 
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you are want to achieve here, do you want the user not to able to choose the time which is already passed?  provide some code that you wen through so far

Comment: yes I wanted exactly similar functionality @EmadDehnavi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged `JQuery`, you can use JQuery [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to disable the options.
This will not allow user to select any `Hour` or `Min` less than current Hour and Min.

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var min = new Date().getMinutes();

$("#hr option").each(function() {

  if (hour > $(this).val())
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);

});

$("#min option").each(function() {

  if (min > $(this).val())
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="select-container">
    <select class="form-control sel-event" id="hr" name="hours" required>
                <option value="">Choose Time/Hr</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="select-container">
    <select class="form-control sel-event" id="min" name="minutes" required>
                <option value="">Choose Time/Min</option>
                <option value="00">00 Min</option>
                <option value="15">15 Min</option>
                <option value="30">30 Min</option>
                <option value="45">45 Min</option>
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, it is working but it should work only for today's date but it is blocking all the timing if it is less than current time on all the dates @Arun CM

Comment: @HemantNagori You can do it by checking selected date == current date. `if(DatePickerSelectedDate == new Date())`.

Answer (score 1):

When it came to date and time, I always go with moment.js. for what you need, moment.js have something usefull called [difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) which can measure diffrence in years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. in your case, you need to pass the user selected date/time to the method, look at this example :

```
var userTime = "14:52";
var stt = new Date("Mar 02, 2018 " + userTime);
stt = stt.getTime();

var a = moment(stt);

if (a.diff()<0){
  alert("Time is passed already!")
}else {
  alert("You still have time!")
}
```

basically, diff() will return an integer which is the difference between given date/time with current time. so if the result is negative, then it means it's already passed!

http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/15783/

Comment: Hello @Emad Dehnavi, I am using the drop down so it won't work. I am using onBlur events. Thanks for your time.